# jQuery nested sortable plugin almost working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-sortable

Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s28Jj/1/).

I'm using the nested sortable plugin, but for some reason you are unable to drag a child `<li>` out of its parent.  The thing is, the problem only occurs if the element is initially in the second tier.  If you start off with all `<li>` elements on the first tier, you can drag them in and out of parent elements with no problem.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add 'items' to the options:

```
$(function(){
    $('#menu-item-sort-list').nestedSortable({
        listType: 'ul',
        items: 'li'
    });
});​
```

Docs [here](https://github.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This is mentioned in "usage", but missing from the list of custom options (where I was looking :P)

Comment: No probs. It's often easier with fresh eyes :)